# SQL - Cursors taking an hour for my query (too long)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, cursors

I'm going to post the code but first im going to explain what im trying to accomplish through pseudo code.

I'm inserting duplicated records in a temporary table.  Then I wanted to examine each record in that table individually to do a select that matches that record and based off that, mark a field final for all the records ('Y', 'N', 'E'). To achieve this I've used 2 cursors and its awful. It's awful because its a lot of hard to read, nasty code and it also make my query take over an hour to run. Is there anyway to make it run better with selects/updates?

Following is the code:

```
declare @hic [nvarchar](255)
declare @oscar [float] 
declare @typecode [float] 
declare @fromdate [datetime] 
declare @thrudate [datetime] 
declare @claimcode [float] 
declare @claimeffdate [datetime] 

declare @id [int]
declare @finalhic [nvarchar](255)
declare @finaloscar [float] 
declare @finaltypecode [float] 
declare @finalfromdate [datetime] 
declare @finalthrudate [datetime] 
declare @finalclaimcode [float] 
declare @finalclaimeffdate [datetime]

declare cur1 CURSOR LOCAL for
select   
     [HIC #], 
     [Provider Oscar #],
     [Claim Type Code], 
     [Claim From Date], 
     [Claim Thru Date],
     [Claim Adjustment Type Code]  from #tmp_hic_cancels

open cur1
fetch next from cur1 into @hic, @oscar, @typecode, @fromdate, @thrudate,     @claimcode
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN

--select @hic, @oscar, @typecode, @fromdate, @thrudate, @claimcode
begin

--typecode = 10
if @typecode = 10
BEGIN
    insert into  #tmp_hic_cancel_batch
    select 
        [ID],
    [HIC #], 
    [Provider Oscar #], 
    [Claim Type Code],
    [Claim From Date], 
    [Claim Thru Date],
    [Claim Adjustment Type Code],
    [Claim Effective Date]
    from [ACO].[dbo].['PA_Header_Temp']
    where [HIC #] = @hic
    and  [Claim Type Code] = @typecode
        and [Provider Oscar #] = @oscar
        and [Claim From Date] = @fromdate 


    --Mark final based on claimcode
    DECLARE Cur2 CURSOR FOR
     select 
     [ID],
    [HIC #], 
    [Provider Oscar #], 
    [Claim Type Code],
    [Claim From Date], 
    [Claim Thru Date],
    [Claim Adjustment Type Code],
    [Claim Effective Date]
         from #tmp_hic_cancel_batch
    OPEN Cur2;
    FETCH NEXT FROM Cur2 INTO @id, @finalhic, @finaloscar, @finaltypecode, @finalfromdate, @finalthrudate, @finalclaimcode, @finalclaimeffdate;
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    --BEGIN CUR2
    BEGIN
    --IF A 2 EXISTS IN BATCH, perform these operations
        if (EXISTS (select 
            [Claim Adjustment Type Code] 
        from [ACO].[dbo].['PA_Header_Temp']
        where [HIC #] = @finalhic
            and [Provider Oscar #] = @finaloscar
            and [Claim Type Code] = @finaltypecode
            and [Claim From Date] = @finalfromdate
            and [Claim Adjustment Type Code] = @finalclaimcode
            and [Claim Adjustment Type Code]  = 2))
        BEGIN
        --MARK FINAL CODES BASED ON CLAIM CODES
            if @finalclaimcode = 2
            begin
                    insert into #tmp_hic_final
                    select @id, @finalhic, @finaloscar, @finaltypecode, @finalfromdate, @finalthrudate, @finalclaimcode, @finalclaimeffdate
                    , 'Y', DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
            end
            else
            begin
                    insert into #tmp_hic_final
                    select @id, @finalhic, @finaloscar, @finaltypecode, @finalfromdate, @finalthrudate, @finalclaimcode, @finalclaimeffdate
                    ,'N', DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
            end
        END
        --IF NO 2 EXISTS IN BATCH
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            if @finalclaimcode = 1
            begin
                    insert into #tmp_hic_final
                    select @id, @finalhic, @finaloscar, @finaltypecode, @finalfromdate, @finalthrudate, @finalclaimcode, @finalclaimeffdate
                    ,'N', DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
            end
        END 
        --END IF NO 2 EXISTS IN BATCH

        FETCH NEXT FROM Cur2 INTO @id, @finalhic, @finaloscar, @finaltypecode, @finalfromdate, @finalthrudate, @finalclaimcode, @finalclaimeffdate
    END;
    --END CUR2
    CLOSE Cur2;
    DEALLOCATE Cur2;

END--END typecode = 10

--else typecode = 40...
else
BEGIN
    insert into #tmp_hic_cancel_batch
    select 
        [ID],
    [HIC #], 
    [Provider Oscar #], 
    [Claim Type Code],
    [Claim From Date], 
    [Claim Thru Date],
    [Claim Adjustment Type Code],
    [Claim Effective Date]
    from [ACO].[dbo].['PA_Header_Temp']
    where [HIC #] = @hic
    and [Provider Oscar #] = @oscar
    and [Claim Type Code] = @typecode
    and [Claim From Date] = @fromdate 
    and [Claim Thru Date] = @thrudate
    and [Claim Adjustment Type Code] = @claimcode

--Mark final based on claimcode
    DECLARE Cur2 CURSOR FOR
     select
     [ID],
    [HIC #], 
    [Provider Oscar #], 
    [Claim Type Code],
    [Claim From Date], 
    [Claim Thru Date],
    [Claim Adjustment Type Code],
    [Claim Effective Date]
         from #tmp_hic_cancel_batch
    OPEN Cur2;
    FETCH NEXT FROM Cur2 INTO @id, @finalhic, @finaloscar, @finaltypecode, @finalfromdate, @finalthrudate, @finalclaimcode, @finalclaimeffdate
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    --BEGIN CUR2
    BEGIN
    --IF A 2 EXISTS IN BATCH, perform these operations
        if (EXISTS (select 
            [Claim Adjustment Type Code] 
        from [ACO].[dbo].['PA_Header_Temp']
        where [HIC #] = @finalhic
            and [Claim Type Code] = @finaltypecode
            and [Provider Oscar #] = @finaloscar
            and [Claim From Date] = @finalfromdate
            and [Claim Thru Date] = @finalthrudate
            and [Claim Adjustment Type Code] = @finalclaimcode
            and [Claim Adjustment Type Code]  = 2))
        BEGIN
        --MARK FINAL CODES BASED ON CLAIM CODES
            if @finalclaimcode = 2
            begin
                    insert into #tmp_hic_final
                    select @id, @finalhic, @finaloscar, @finaltypecode, @finalfromdate, @finalthrudate, @finalclaimcode, @finalclaimeffdate
                    ,'Y', DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
            end
            else
            begin
                    insert into #tmp_hic_final
                    select @id, @finalhic, @finaloscar, @finaltypecode, @finalfromdate, @finalthrudate, @finalclaimcode, @finalclaimeffdate
                    ,'N', DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
            end
        END
        --IF NO 2 EXISTS IN BATCH
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            if @finalclaimcode = 1
            begin
                    insert into #tmp_hic_final
                    select @id, @finalhic, @finaloscar, @finaltypecode, @finalfromdate, @finalthrudate, @finalclaimcode, @finalclaimeffdate
                    ,'N', DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
            end
            else
            begin
                    insert into #tmp_hic_final
                    select @id, @finalhic, @finaloscar, @finaltypecode, @finalfromdate, @finalthrudate, @finalclaimcode, @finalclaimeffdate
                    ,'Y', DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
            end
        END 
        --END IF NO 2 EXISTS IN BATCH

        FETCH NEXT FROM Cur2 INTO @id, @finalhic, @finaloscar, @finaltypecode, @finalfromdate, @finalthrudate, @finalclaimcode, @finalclaimeffdate
    END;
    --END CUR2
    CLOSE Cur2;
    DEALLOCATE Cur2;

END

    --clears temp table for next batch
    delete from #tmp_hic_cancel_batch

fetch next from cur1 into @hic, @oscar, @typecode, @fromdate, @thrudate, @claimcode
END

close cur1
deallocate cur1
```

Comment: A quick glance doesn't suggest any need for a cursor in the first place, perhaps I've missed something though.

Comment: Sorry, but your code is also too long...

Comment: @HartCO, could you go into more depth

Comment: So much redundant code in there too. Look at the section "--MARK FINAL CODES BASED ON CLAIM CODES" There are three inserts all base on some criteria but every single insert is identical. Same thing in the next section. There are a lot of places in here with conditional branches that do the same thing. This whole thing looks like it could be reduced to 1 or 2 insert statements.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the execution plan to see where in your query it is taking too long?

Comment: @JohnOdom there are nested cursors. We don't need an execution plan to know this performs awful.

Comment: @SeanLange, The inserts are not identical, and they're also in a nested if else (all which im trying to avoid, and why I'm coming here). Not sure how I could do it in a few inserts based in the 10 and 40 typecodes and whether a 2 exists... these conditions are what are throwing me off

Comment: I'm not gonna analyze all that code, but it looks to me that you are using cursors because you are doing different things based on FinalClaimCode being either 1 or 2.  Maybe you can get rid of the cursors and do two different queries/code blocks, one where FinalClaimCode=1 and the other where FinalClaimCode=2.

Comment: When finalclaimcode = 1 or anything other than 2 they are exactly the same. Those three inserts could be reduced to a single insert with a case expression. Here is the problem. You posted a 400 line script with no tables or sample data and want somebody to fix it. Maybe you can break this into two pieces, one for each value in FinalClaimCode.

Comment: There are in fact identicals.  Starting at the comment "--IF NO 2 EXISTS IN BATCH", that next `IF` block does the same thing.  Same columns, same `DATEADD` forumla.  No matter what @finalclaimcode returns, it will do the same code.

Comment: @TabAlleman, whats happening is I'm starting off with if typecode= 10 do stuff, else do stuff.  Then in Each one of those I have to check whether a '2' exists in [Claim Adjustment Type Code] within my 2nd cursor.  Thats when I check based on FinalClaimCode.  It's very complex and I'm not sure of another angle to hit it from why is why I've come to you smart folks :]

Comment: Something about makeup on a pig.  Like @SeanLange said, sample data, table structures, break it up.  Make it easier to decipher.

Comment: @TTeeple, in the first typcecode=10 yes you are correct.  I have fixed that.  In the 2nd block with typecode=40, they are not identical.  Thanks for the minor fix.  I'm looking for a better way to write all this mess.

Comment: So instead of a cursor checking row-by-row, and handling each row differently, write a single statement for each of the sets of data you need to handle differently.

Comment: Modified the code for you all.  Took a lot of unneeded cols out and cleaned the code based on the corrections you mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cursors are the very problem, as you have surmised.  They are terribly inefficient and only appropriate in very limited conditions.  For large scale processing, like this seems to be doing, with even nested operations, cursors are never a good solution.

You will need to go through the whole procedure and extract each bit out of the  cursor.  I will give you the first one, and that is why I am thinking of this as an answer and not just a comment.

The first insert that happens inside the first cursor, could be extracted to just before the whole procedure starts, and it would end up looking like this:

```
insert into  #tmp_hic_cancel_batch                     
select PAHT.[ID],
        PAHT.[HIC #], 
        PAHT.[Provider Oscar #], 
        PAHT.[Claim Type Code],
        PAHT.[Claim From Date], 
        PAHT.[Claim Thru Date],
        PAHT.[Claim Adjustment Type Code],
        PAHT.[Claim Effective Date],
        PAHT.[Current ClaimID],
        PAHT.[Claim Bill Facility Type Code],
        PAHT.[Claim Bill Classification Code],
        PAHT.[Principal Diagnosis Code],
        PAHT.[Admitting Diagnosis Code],
        PAHT.[Claim Medicare Non Payment Reason Code],
        PAHT.[Claim Payment Amount],
        PAHT.[Claim NCH Primary Payer Code],
        PAHT.[FIPS state Code],
        PAHT.[Bene Patient Status Code],
        PAHT.[Diagnosis Related Group Code],
        PAHT.[Claim Outpatient Service Type Code],
        PAHT.[Facility Provider NPI #],
        PAHT.[Operating Provider NPI #],
        PAHT.[Attending provider NPI #],
        PAHT.[Other Provider NPI #],
        PAHT.[Claim IDR Load Date],
        PAHT.[Bene Equitable BIC HICN #],
        PAHT.[Claim Admission Type Code],
        PAHT.[Claim Admission Source Code],
        PAHT.[Claim Bill Frequency Code],
        PAHT.[Claim Query Code],
from [ACO].[dbo].['PA_Header_Temp'] PAHT
        inner join #tmp_hic_cancels THC on PAHT.[HIC #] = THC.[HIC #] and
                                        PAHT.[Claim Type Code] = THC.[Claim Type Code] and 
                                        PAHT.[Provider Oscar #] = THC.[Provider Oscar #] and
                                        PAHT.[Claim From Date] = THC.[Claim From Date] 
where PAHT.[Claim Type Code] = 10
```

You would then have to move on to the next bit inside the next cursor, and extract it the same way, changing a cursor operation into a combination of selects with the appropriate joins.

You would probably find that the whole thing reduces to a couple of queries.  Or, if one knew enough about the specifics of the problem, one could come up with those queries straight out.  But it would take a few hours to do this for the whole procedure, so I am not going to attempt the whole thing.  Also, I am fairly sure the above is correct, but there is no way for me to test it, so...

Yes, this can be made a LOT faster and more efficient.  This can be done with just queries (selects, inserts, updates), an NO cursors.  But there is no way you are going to get someone to do the whole thing for you for free.

Comment: I appreciate your help.  I plan on doing it, but just needed a bit of code to put me in the right direction. I had to put the whole bit of code to explain (I guess poorly :/) exactly what i was trying to accomplish.  This looks good I'll mark it as an answer after some testing.

Comment: Your explanation was fine.  It's just that it is a big problem.  And, in learning how to use SQL most of us, myself included, have fallen into the trap of using cursors and have had to learn the hard way to avoid them at all costs.  It's just part of the territory.

Comment: Yes, cursors will never be used again, especially since the faster alternative can used  in implementing aselect/insert/update. Learning from experience myself as well friend :]

Answer (score 1):

Using @Gilchrist code as a base this is what I've used to fix my code form cursor to 4 actual sql insert into selects...
It checks for typecode = 20 and a 2 to exist, then typecode = 20 and not a 2.
The 2nd set is typecode <> 20 and a 2 exist, then typecode <> 20 and not a 2.

Hope someone can find this useful someday:

```
insert into  #tmp_hic_final                     
select distinct PAHT.[ID],
    PAHT.[HIC #], 
    PAHT.[Provider Oscar #], 
    PAHT.[Claim Type Code],
    PAHT.[Claim From Date], 
    PAHT.[Claim Thru Date],
    PAHT.[Claim Adjustment Type Code],
    PAHT.[Claim Effective Date],
    PAHT.[Current ClaimID],
    PAHT.[Claim Bill Facility Type Code],
    PAHT.[Claim Bill Classification Code],
    PAHT.[Principal Diagnosis Code],
    PAHT.[Admitting Diagnosis Code],
    PAHT.[Claim Medicare Non Payment Reason Code],
    PAHT.[Claim Payment Amount],
    PAHT.[Claim NCH Primary Payer Code],
    PAHT.[FIPS state Code],
    PAHT.[Bene Patient Status Code],
    PAHT.[Diagnosis Related Group Code],
    PAHT.[Claim Outpatient Service Type Code],
    PAHT.[Facility Provider NPI #],
    PAHT.[Operating Provider NPI #],
    PAHT.[Attending provider NPI #],
    PAHT.[Other Provider NPI #],
    PAHT.[Claim IDR Load Date],
    PAHT.[Bene Equitable BIC HICN #],
    PAHT.[Claim Admission Type Code],
    PAHT.[Claim Admission Source Code],
    PAHT.[Claim Bill Frequency Code],
    PAHT.[Claim Query Code],
    CASE 
        WHEN PAHT.[Claim Adjustment Type Code] = '2' THEN 'Y'
        ELSE 'N' 
    END,
    DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
from [ACO].[dbo].['PA_Header_Temp'] PAHT
    inner join #tmp_hic_cancels THC on PAHT.[HIC #] = THC.[HIC #] and
                                    PAHT.[Claim Type Code] = THC.[Claim Type Code] and 
                                    PAHT.[Provider Oscar #] = THC.[Provider Oscar #] and
                                    PAHT.[Claim From Date] = THC.[Claim From Date] and
                                    PAHT.[Claim Adjustment Type Code] = THC.[Claim Adjustment Type Code]
where PAHT.[Claim Type Code] = 10
    and EXISTS (select 
                [Claim Adjustment Type Code] 
            from [ACO].[dbo].['PA_Header_Temp']
            where 
                [HIC #] = PAHT.[HIC #]
                and [Provider Oscar #] = PAHT.[Provider Oscar #]
                and [Claim Type Code] = PAHT.[Claim Type Code]
                and [Claim From Date] = PAHT.[Claim From Date]
                and [Claim Adjustment Type Code] = PAHT.[Claim Adjustment Type Code]
                and [Claim Adjustment Type Code]  = 2)

insert into  #tmp_hic_final  
select distinct PAHT.[ID],
    PAHT.[HIC #], 
    PAHT.[Provider Oscar #], 
    PAHT.[Claim Type Code],
    PAHT.[Claim From Date], 
    PAHT.[Claim Thru Date],
    PAHT.[Claim Adjustment Type Code],
    PAHT.[Claim Effective Date],
    PAHT.[Current ClaimID],
    PAHT.[Claim Bill Facility Type Code],
    PAHT.[Claim Bill Classification Code],
    PAHT.[Principal Diagnosis Code],
    PAHT.[Admitting Diagnosis Code],
    PAHT.[Claim Medicare Non Payment Reason Code],
    PAHT.[Claim Payment Amount],
    PAHT.[Claim NCH Primary Payer Code],
    PAHT.[FIPS state Code],
    PAHT.[Bene Patient Status Code],
    PAHT.[Diagnosis Related Group Code],
    PAHT.[Claim Outpatient Service Type Code],
    PAHT.[Facility Provider NPI #],
    PAHT.[Operating Provider NPI #],
    PAHT.[Attending provider NPI #],
    PAHT.[Other Provider NPI #],
    PAHT.[Claim IDR Load Date],
    PAHT.[Bene Equitable BIC HICN #],
    PAHT.[Claim Admission Type Code],
    PAHT.[Claim Admission Source Code],
    PAHT.[Claim Bill Frequency Code],
    PAHT.[Claim Query Code],
    'N',
    DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
from [ACO].[dbo].['PA_Header_Temp'] PAHT
    inner join #tmp_hic_cancels THC on PAHT.[HIC #] = THC.[HIC #] and
                                    PAHT.[Claim Type Code] = THC.[Claim Type Code] and 
                                    PAHT.[Provider Oscar #] = THC.[Provider Oscar #] and
                                    PAHT.[Claim From Date] = THC.[Claim From Date]  and
                                    PAHT.[Claim Adjustment Type Code] = THC.[Claim Adjustment Type Code]
where PAHT.[Claim Type Code] = 10
    and EXISTS (select 
                [Claim Adjustment Type Code] 
            from [ACO].[dbo].['PA_Header_Temp']
            where 
                [HIC #] = PAHT.[HIC #]
                and [Provider Oscar #] = PAHT.[Provider Oscar #]
                and [Claim Type Code] = PAHT.[Claim Type Code]
                and [Claim From Date] = PAHT.[Claim From Date]
                and [Claim Adjustment Type Code] = PAHT.[Claim Adjustment Type Code]
                and [Claim Adjustment Type Code]  <> 2)

insert into  #tmp_hic_final  
select distinct PAHT.[ID],
    PAHT.[HIC #], 
    PAHT.[Provider Oscar #], 
    PAHT.[Claim Type Code],
    PAHT.[Claim From Date], 
    PAHT.[Claim Thru Date],
    PAHT.[Claim Adjustment Type Code],
    PAHT.[Claim Effective Date],
    PAHT.[Current ClaimID],
    PAHT.[Claim Bill Facility Type Code],
    PAHT.[Claim Bill Classification Code],
    PAHT.[Principal Diagnosis Code],
    PAHT.[Admitting Diagnosis Code],
    PAHT.[Claim Medicare Non Payment Reason Code],
    PAHT.[Claim Payment Amount],
    PAHT.[Claim NCH Primary Payer Code],
    PAHT.[FIPS state Code],
    PAHT.[Bene Patient Status Code],
    PAHT.[Diagnosis Related Group Code],
    PAHT.[Claim Outpatient Service Type Code],
    PAHT.[Facility Provider NPI #],
    PAHT.[Operating Provider NPI #],
    PAHT.[Attending provider NPI #],
    PAHT.[Other Provider NPI #],
    PAHT.[Claim IDR Load Date],
    PAHT.[Bene Equitable BIC HICN #],
    PAHT.[Claim Admission Type Code],
    PAHT.[Claim Admission Source Code],
    PAHT.[Claim Bill Frequency Code],
    PAHT.[Claim Query Code],
    'N',
    DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
 from [ACO].[dbo].['PA_Header_Temp'] PAHT
    inner join #tmp_hic_cancels THC on PAHT.[HIC #] = THC.[HIC #] and
                                    PAHT.[Claim Type Code] = THC.[Claim Type Code] and 
                                    PAHT.[Provider Oscar #] = THC.[Provider Oscar #] and
                                    PAHT.[Claim From Date] = THC.[Claim From Date] and
                                     PAHT.[Claim Thru Date] = THC.[Claim Thru Date]
where PAHT.[Claim Type Code] <> 10
    and EXISTS (select 
                [Claim Adjustment Type Code] 
            from [ACO].[dbo].['PA_Header_Temp']
            where 
                [HIC #] = PAHT.[HIC #]
                and [Provider Oscar #] = PAHT.[Provider Oscar #]
                and [Claim Type Code] = PAHT.[Claim Type Code]
                and [Claim From Date] = PAHT.[Claim From Date]
                and [Claim Adjustment Type Code] = PAHT.[Claim Adjustment Type Code]
                and [Claim Adjustment Type Code]  = 2)

insert into  #tmp_hic_final  
select distinct PAHT.[ID],
    PAHT.[HIC #], 
    PAHT.[Provider Oscar #], 
    PAHT.[Claim Type Code],
    PAHT.[Claim From Date], 
    PAHT.[Claim Thru Date],
    PAHT.[Claim Adjustment Type Code],
    PAHT.[Claim Effective Date],
    PAHT.[Current ClaimID],
    PAHT.[Claim Bill Facility Type Code],
    PAHT.[Claim Bill Classification Code],
    PAHT.[Principal Diagnosis Code],
    PAHT.[Admitting Diagnosis Code],
    PAHT.[Claim Medicare Non Payment Reason Code],
    PAHT.[Claim Payment Amount],
    PAHT.[Claim NCH Primary Payer Code],
    PAHT.[FIPS state Code],
    PAHT.[Bene Patient Status Code],
    PAHT.[Diagnosis Related Group Code],
    PAHT.[Claim Outpatient Service Type Code],
    PAHT.[Facility Provider NPI #],
    PAHT.[Operating Provider NPI #],
    PAHT.[Attending provider NPI #],
    PAHT.[Other Provider NPI #],
    PAHT.[Claim IDR Load Date],
    PAHT.[Bene Equitable BIC HICN #],
    PAHT.[Claim Admission Type Code],
    PAHT.[Claim Admission Source Code],
    PAHT.[Claim Bill Frequency Code],
    PAHT.[Claim Query Code],
    'N',
    DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
from [ACO].[dbo].['PA_Header_Temp'] PAHT
    inner join #tmp_hic_cancels THC on PAHT.[HIC #] = THC.[HIC #] and
                                    PAHT.[Claim Type Code] = THC.[Claim Type Code] and 
                                    PAHT.[Provider Oscar #] = THC.[Provider Oscar #] and
                                    PAHT.[Claim From Date] = THC.[Claim From Date] and
                                     PAHT.[Claim Thru Date] = THC.[Claim Thru Date]
where PAHT.[Claim Type Code] <> 10
    and EXISTS (select 
                [Claim Adjustment Type Code] 
            from [ACO].[dbo].['PA_Header_Temp']
            where 
                [HIC #] = PAHT.[HIC #]
                and [Provider Oscar #] = PAHT.[Provider Oscar #]
                and [Claim Type Code] = PAHT.[Claim Type Code]
                and [Claim From Date] = PAHT.[Claim From Date]
                and [Claim Adjustment Type Code] = PAHT.[Claim Adjustment Type Code]
                and [Claim Adjustment Type Code]  <> 2)
```